# Black Login Screen Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: login-screen, 15.04

After updating from 14.10 to 15.04, the login screen is black. Just by changing the mouse pointer do I find the password text field; password typed in and then all works normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a bug, but perhaps graphics driver issue ,too. I'd file bug report and switch for the time being to another greeter like `lightdm-gtk-greeter` or `gdm`

Comment: bug report is a good idea :) we can log in then all works fine, after we have found the text field :D

Comment: the funny what we have discovered today, when u let the login screen go to power save and switch the screen off and you reactive the screen the picture / login screen is visiable ....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Logging in the terminal mode (Alt+F1) and running the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

and rebooting fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install another greeter, like `gdm`, then run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to switch to it.

Comment: the funny what we have discovered today, when u let the login screen go to power save and switch the screen off and you reactive the screen the picture / login screen is visiable ....